# Proof that if poly $f \in \mathbb F_3$ of deg 4 or 5 with no roots is reducible then there is a monic irreducible polynomial of deg 2 dividing $f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Since $\mathbb F_3[X]$ is a unique factorization domain there exists a unique factorization of irreducible elements. I know these must have degree 2 and 2 for $f$ of degree 4, and degree 2 and 3 for $f$ of degree 5. But how do i know any of these, or specifically the one with degree 2, are monic?

Comment: Suppose you find a second degree polynomial which is not monic. Simply multiply the whole polynomial by the multiplicative inverse of the leading coefficient

Comment: Ah, right, thanks. I misunderstood what a unique factorization meant. Thought it ment unique in the literal sense.

Answer (score 0):

Leading coefficients in polynomials are like signs in prime numbers.
Positive prime numbers and monic irreducible polynomials are canonical representatives of irreducible elements.

Compare:

- Every integer has a unique factorization into positive prime numbers plus a sign:
  $$
  n = \pm \, p_1 \cdots p_m
  $$
- Every polynomial over a field has a unique factorization into irreducible monic polynomials plus a leading coefficient:
  $$
  f = a \, p_1 \cdots p_m
  $$

Uniqueness in both cases is up to order.